# Recursive run function on value by key in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, str-replace, conventions

I want to run function or replace value by the key of multi-dimensional array.

This is example of array I have.

```
  'data' => array
    (
        '0' => array
        (
            'id' => '2039'
            'status' => 'OK'
            'date' => 1382339688
        )
        '1' => array
        (
            'id' => '33000'
            'status' => 'OK'
            'date' => 1378645263
        )
        '2' => array
        (
            'id' => '18800'
            'status' => 'Failed'
            'date' => 1381224889
        )
        '3' => array
        (
            'id' => '34522'
            'status' => 'OK'
            'date' => 1378973015000
        )
)
```

For example of function I want to call.

> recursive_array_replace_by_key($array, $key, $function);

If want to fix all dates in array I will do:

> recursive_array_replace_by_key($array, 'date, gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $value)); //Convert all date values to formatted date.

To replace all status:

> recursive_array_replace_by_key($array, 'status, 'NA'); //Convert all status values to NA

I want to ability to search in the array without to know how long the structure is.

Answer (score 1):

I think below function can help you do so.

```
function formatdate($array,$field,$format)
{
    foreach($array as $arr)
    {
        $arr[$field]=date($format,$arr[$field]);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Call above function like this `formatdate($array,'date','Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');`

Hope this helps

Comment: Its very specific solution. I want something more generic I can run on any function or type of data and with recursive replace option.